# Is the brain functionally symmetrical?

Tags: neuroscience

I understand that each half of the human brain handles different parts of our thinking. Left brain, right brain, that whole topic.

But in pictures, the brain is always depicted as having symmetrical structure. I'm curious about that. I realize that it might be silly to expect such a complex tool to be *truly* symmetrical, so my question is:

**Is the brain *functionally* symmetrical or not?** By functionally, I'm referring to whether the specialized groups within the brain all exists on both sides or rather each side contains different components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For instance, Broca's area exists only in the frontal lobe of one hemisphere, usually the left. (it's responsible for speech, btw)